# elementaryos-6.1-stable.20211218-rc can not install Vmware Workstation Pro 16.2

Tags: system-installation

I try elementaryos-6.1 to install Vmware Workstation Pro 16.2. But at first,elementaryos installer say "boot status daemon failed".So instalation stop 70% configured status.How do I set up elementaryos?

Hardware:DELL G5000 C: 1T D: 2T SSD
Vmware Workstation configure:
1.Type Linux (Ubuntu 64bit)
2.Boot from EFI (Bios can not use,Beacuse installer screen are cut)
3.ISO Image boot and install.elementaryos-6.1-stable.20211218-rc.iso[image]

Comment: T forget the message.Boot "error: Unexpectedly disconnected from boot status daemon" What is this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it and installed. All Language and Keybord choice default US English.
Elementaryos-6.1 was finished to configure system setting. Then I choose and setting Japanese locale, my profile. It's OK.